# How can I read a CSV file with headers in Webix datatable?

Tags: csv, webix

I want to read a CSV file with headers to populate a `datatable` widget following this [documentation](http://docs.webix.com/datatable__loading_data.html#loadingfromxmlcsvjsarray). However, I get an `uncaught exception: [object XMLHttpRequest]` error when I execute the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix.css" type="text/css"> 
    <script src="http://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix_debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.opencpu.org/opencpu-0.4.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
webix.ui({
    rows:[
        { view:"template", 
          type:"header", template:"Read in a CSV" },
        { view:"datatable", 
          columns:[
              { id:"#x#", header:"x" },
              { id:"#y#", header:"y" },
              { id:"#z#", header:"z" }],
          datatype:"csv",
          autoheight:true,
          autowidth:true,
          url:"data/basic.csv"
        }
    ]
});
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In addition, I see the following notifications appear in the upper right-hand corner of the browser.

[image: webix error notifications]

The error details from the log are:

```
"XHTTP:" XMLHttpRequest { onreadystatechange: webix.ajax.prototype._send/x.onreadystatechange(), readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, status: 0, statusText: "", responseType: "", response: "x,y,z
1,1,23.3
1,2,15.8
2,1,88.3
2,2,83.5
", responseText: "x,y,z
1,1,23.3
1,2,15.8
2,1,88.3
2,2,83.5
" } webix_debug.js:3240
uncaught exception: [object XMLHttpRequest]
```

It appears to read the CSV file just fine. Why doesn't it display? I have to admit, I find the documentation confusing as it doesn't mention CSV headers at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you run the sample page by the http (with some kind of web server), or open it directly from a file system?

Due to security limitations, ajax request may not work for pages that was loaded directly from a file system.

Also, to map data correctly, you need to use datatable columns config like next

```
      columns:[
          { id:"data0", header:"x" },
          { id:"data1", header:"y" },
          { id:"data2", header:"z" }],
```

DataTable will not recognize header and map CSV data to abstract data0..dataN properties.

Comment: I'm opening it from the file system. I'll see if I can find some sort of personal web server to host it.